# Calculate nanmean in groupby and apply this mean to DF column according to subgroup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mean

I am trying to fill in missing values for the user_score column in my DataFrame. The data is currently strings, including `'tbd'`. I was looking to replace `'tbd'` values with `NaN`, then convert the column to float, and then calculate the `user_score` mean by game genre and apply this mean to each NaN value in the `user_score` column, based on their genre (instead of using overall user_score mean).

```
games['user_score'] = games['user_score'].replace('tbd', np.nan, inplace=True)
games['user_score'] = games['user_score'].astype(float)
#genre_mean = games.groupby('genre').agg({'user_score':np.mean})
games['user_score'] = games.groupby('genre', sort=False)['user_score'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
print(games.groupby('genre').agg({'user_score':np.mean}))
print(games['user_score'].head(10))
```

Now when I print the groupby at the end of my code, it shows me the mean of the user_score per genre as NaN for each genre. I then tried using `.nanmean()` in the apply function but it gave me an error. How can I apply user_score mean per game genre to missing values in the user_score column, based on their genre?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user_score` is turning null in the first line:

```py
games['user_score'] = games['user_score'].replace('tbd', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

If you assign `user_score` *and* use `inplace=True` at the same time, that will wipe out `user_score`.

Either assign back without `inplace`:

```py
games['user_score'] = games['user_score'].replace('tbd', np.nan)
```

Or use `inplace` without assigning back:

```py
games['user_score'].replace('tbd', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!! It also makes a lot of sense now.